# TypeError: myscroll.get(...) is undefined while scrolling in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, frontend

```
    function scroll_top(){ 
        myscroll = $('.simplebar-scroll-content');
        myscroll.scrollTop(myscroll.get(0).scrollHeight);
    }
```

This code is working fine in chrome browser but not working in firefox.It is giving `TypeError: myscroll.get(...)` is undefined while calling `scrollTop` function.